# BASH Set multiple variables depending on number of lines then pass them as command arguments

Tags: bash

I have this output after command:

```
$some_command
id
274725
275050
275065
277560
277801
277814
277817
277862
277863
```

I need ignore the first line and set all numbers as variables:

```
var1=274725
var2=275050
...
...
var9=277863
```

then I want to run command with those variables as parameters:

$some_cmd $var1 $var2 ...$varN

with my very limited knowledge I have idea how to figure out the number of variables:

```
varN1=`some_command | wc -l`
varsN=`expr $varN1 - 1`
```

But this won't be easiest solution and I don't know how to make the loop where I will set the variables and how to construct the command. Perhaps something like?:

```
for i in (1...$varsN)
do
var$i=.... ?
```

Comment: you can try this `set $(some_command); shift` then all of them will be placed as `$1` .. `$N` and `$#` will be the number of variables. The array variable `$@` will also be set. You can then call a new program and pass the array like `newprog "$@"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're putting them into variables simply so you can pass them to another function/program. That's not actually necessary.

`xargs`, the program that runs multiple child tasks on groups of input parameters, has an option to limit the number of parametres it passes to each of it's tasks:

```
pax> echo 'id
274725
275050
275065
277560
277801
277814
277817
277862
277863' | awk 'NR>1{print}' | xargs -n 4 echo runcommand 
runcommand 274725 275050 275065 277560
runcommand 277801 277814 277817 277862
runcommand 277863
```

The `awk` command simply strips out the first line then `xargs -n 4` will run the child task `echo runcommand` for each grouping of up to that size.

Answer (score 0):

To run a command with all the numbers in your files as separate arguments, you can use

```
yourcommand $(some_command | sed 1d)
```

Note that this assumes that your lines are all numbers, and not strings with spaces and other ascii characters you want to preserve.